# Character Convert Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, character

I am trying to make a text converter for file names with regex, in this text there are some different dash types and hyphen types minus signs etc.etc. I want to convert them all to just a simple hyphen.

there are several types of different dashes and their unicodes are here:

```
u2212 u002D u05BE u2011 u2012 u2013 u2014 u2015 u207B u208B u2212 uFE58 uFE63 uFF0D
```

if a character is one of these unicodes, then I want to convert it to **simple hyphen which is u2010** with regex.

How can make this character convert regex with java ?

At first I was checking the file name is valid or not like this:

```
private static final Pattern FILE_NAME = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\u2212\\u002D\\u00AD\\u05BE\\u2010\\u2011\\u2012\\u2013\\u2014\\u2015\\u207B\\u208B\\u2212\\uFE58\\uFE63\\uFF0D\\.\\s\\,\\[\\]()\\{\\}]+$");

if (!FILE_NAME.matcher(file.getFilename()).matches()) {
                throw new FileValidationException(FILE_NAME_INVALID);
}
```

but now I don't want to validate it I just want to replace characters with hyphen u2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like:

```
name = name.replaceAll("[\u2212\u002D\u00AD\u05BE"
        + "\u2011\u2012\u2013\u2014\u2015\u207B\u208B\u2212\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]", "\u2010");
```

Here `\u2212` are in java chars with the 4-digit hexadecimal values of UTF-16.
There is no magic, `\u0063` is the same as `c` like in `public \u0063lass X { }`.

Resource for [dash like Unicode](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd).

Answer (score 3):

Use `<TargetString>.replaceAll(<pattern>, <replacement>)` (See: [Java 8 API: String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-))

In your case this would be: `file.getFilename().replaceAll(FILE_NAME.toString(), "\u2010")`

Comment: But I would strongly suggest a different variable name for the pattern...

Comment: thanks but here I want to only convert dashes minus signs that I mentioned whose unicodes, not letters so can you right the regex pattern correctly ?

Comment: just remove them from your regex, just keep the stuff in there that you want replaced

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
fileName.replaceAll("\u2212|\u002D|\u05BE|\u2011|\u2012|\u2013|\u2014|\u2015|\u207B|\u208B|\u2212|\uFE58|\uFE63|\uFF0D", "\u2010");
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the `replaceAll()` method on `file.getFilename()` as shown below:

```
file.getFilename().replaceAll(FILE_NAME.toString() ,"\\u2010");
```